# I am trying to make a Quicksort with a GUI my code broke

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, tkinter, quicksort

please keep functions the same as this is for a school project where we are supposed to show our understanding of the code. I'm not sure what has happened and need a hand fixing it, when clicking "Quick Sort" on the GUI and error pops up saying that "low" has not been defined. Thanks in Advance.

````
# This function takes last element as pivot, places
# the pivot element at its correct position in sorted
# array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot)
# to left of pivot and all greater elements to right
# of pivot
#Add Function
def add():
    global label_result
    newNumber = int(passwordEntry.get())
    arr.append(newNumber)
    label_result = tk.Label(master, text=str(arr))
    label_result.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)


def partition(arr, low, high):
    i = (low-1)         # index of smaller element
    pivot = arr[high]     # pivot

    for j in range(low, high):

        # If current element is smaller than or
        # equal to pivot
        if arr[j] <= pivot:

            # increment index of smaller element
            i = i+1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1]
    return (i+1)

# The main function that implements QuickSort
# arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
# low  --> Starting index,
# high  --> Ending index

# Function to do Quick sort


def quickSort(arr, low, high):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    if low < high:

        # pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
        # at right place
        pi = partition(arr, low, high)

        # Separately sort elements before
        # partition and after partition
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1)
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high)


# Driver code to test above
arr = []
n = len(arr)
quickSort(arr, 0, n-1)
print("Sorted array is:")
for i in range(n):
    print("%d" % arr[i]),

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Dans Quick Sort")
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(master)
passwordEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(master, text='Enter Number: ', font='bold',).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(master, text='Add to Array', command=add).grid(row=1, column=0)
#lambda allows you to call a function with parameter.
tk.Button(master, text='Quick Sort', command=lambda: partition(arr, low, high)).grid(row=1, column=1)
label_msg = tk.Label(master, text='')
label_msg.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)```
````

Comment: try hardcoding it in the lambda given as the command argumen tin the call to tk.Button as 0, is it supposed to be the int( of the inputted text?

Comment: yes it is supposed to be Dave. Could you give me a hand with it ? They are supposed to input numbers adding to the array then quick sort in the GUI.

Comment: so try replacing low with 0 in that line

Comment: and high with len(arr)

Comment: Ok, it said :
```Sorted array is:
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\users\danie\mu_code\quicksort gui.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    tk.Button(master, text='Quick Sort', command=lambda: partition(arr, 0, len(arr))).grid(row=1, column=1)
  File "c:\users\danie\mu_code\quicksort gui.py", line 18, in partition
    pivot = arr[high]     # pivot
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: oh, sorry i meant `len(arr) - 1`

Comment: Ok here is the code, now when i press "Quick Sort" in the GUI nothing happens lol

Comment: Could you please try put the code in your text editor and get it to work <3?

Comment: Someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

You executed `partition(...)` in the `lambda` which will not do the sorting.

Create a function to execute `quickSort()` function and show the result in a label:

```py
def add():
    newNumber = int(passwordEntry.get())
    arr.append(newNumber)
    label_msg.config(text=str(arr)) # used label_msg instead of creating new label

...

def doQuickSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    quickSort(arr, 0, n-1)
    result.config(text=str(arr))  # update the result label

...
arr = []
tk.Button(master, text='Quick Sort', command=lambda: doQuickSort(arr)).grid(row=1, column=1)
label_msg = tk.Label(master, text='')
label_msg.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
# label for the sorting result
result = tk.Label(master)
result.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
```